# How can we create new playlist and add or delete songs form the playlist in android using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, playlist

How can we create new playlist and add or delete songs form the playlist

i have created a listview which gets all the playlists which are available on the phone and displays in a list but how can we create new playlist and add or delete songs from the existing playlist

this is the playlist code which is just for reference it doesnot have any functionality to  add or delete any songs

```
public class playlist extends ListActivity {

    //define source of MediaStore.Images.Media, internal or external storage
    Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] from = {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                this, 
                sourceUri, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);

        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                cursor, 
                from, 
                to, 
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        setListAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
    }
```